# Upload ZIP and unzip it to prevent timestamp getting actualized

Tags: java, ftp, zip, apache-commons-net

I've wanted to compare files on a FTP server with local files. To not modify the timestamp, I've wanted to upload them zipped and then unzip them on the webserver, to prevent the timestamp getting actualized. This was mentioned [here](http://www.unix.com/answers-frequently-asked-questions/29458-ftp-files-but-keep-original-timestamp.html) as a possibility.

But actually I don't know how I can do this (I am using Java and the [Apache Commons FTP-Libraries](http://commons.apache.org/net/).

How can I put a local file into a ZIP-File, upload this one to the server and then unzip it with the same timestamp? Or isn't this possible at all?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: what have you tried so far?  post the code and ask questions about the parts where you are having problems.

Comment: Have just searched this on the net.. i am asking because I don't really understand the use of the FTP protocol in the apache commons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found out that this is not possible using pure FTP. You'd have to use third party software.